# Is there any way to create HTTP proxy on VPN on Android?

Tags: android, proxy, vpn

We have corporate network with propietary protocol for access from outside to internal IP network. The task is give the access from standard android apps (web browser, email client etc.) to internal resources.

We've created app that estaliblishes channel to the network.

So the question is: is there any way to register my app as:

1. HTTP proxy
2. VPN client

... and than catch and redirect all HTTP requests or IP traffic into corporate network over established channel?

Comment: Question is more than 1 year old. were you able to find anything? I am looking for something similar.It is strange ios offers this in such easily configurable way and there is no way to do it in android.

Comment: Starting from android API 14, there is some thing related as VPNService. I am also searching about it.

Comment: Did you meant to use a HTTP proxy as a VPN Service ? In the top layer it's a VPN Service provide to the phone system wide, so that all apps can use it, and in the lower layer it use HTTP(S) (or PAC) proxy to communicate outside world ?

Comment: Looking for same solution